# How to sort array or queryset in "chess order"?

Tags: python, django, sorting

The task is to sort queryset in "chess order". ie:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    CHOICES = [
        (1, 1),
        (2, 2),
        (3, 3),
    ]
    branch = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=CHOICES)

item1.branch == 1
item2.branch == 1
item3.branch == 2
item4.branch == 3
item5.branch == 3
```

The desired output of `Item.objects.all()` would be:

```
[item1, item3, item4, item2, item5]
```

So the resulted queryset would be sorted in a manner where branches are `(1,2,3), (1,2,3), (1,2,3)` etc.

Comment: Do you have more info on what "chess order" is?

Comment: Please provide a link about this "chess order". I'm intrigued.

Comment: If you have a pile of black and white elements, you should organise them in a order similar to a chessboard: black-white-black-white-black-white...etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have never heard of chess sort, but from your description it seems to be defined like this.

> A list *l* with smallest element x<sub>min</sub> and greatest element x<sub>max</sub> is in chess sort order if `l[0]` is x<sub>min</sub> and `l[j]` is recursively picked to minimize the step *k* which is defined as the smallest positive integer such that `l[j-1] + k == l[j]` mod x<sub>max</sub>.

In other words, it's like you were only allowed to place items on the column corresponding to their value on a chessboard. The list is considered sorted if every element is positionned as early as possible on the chessboard.

The problem with such an ordering is that it is not local. This mean that every item being correctly placed with respect to their neighbors does not imply that the whole list is correctly sorted. This is important because it indicates that we will not be able to sort the list with `sorted` and a well-crafted `key` argument.

Although, we can write an algorithm similar to [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) that sorts in *chess order*.

### Code

```
from collections import defaultdict, deque
from itertools import cycle

def chess_sort(lst, key=lambda x: x):
    count = defaultdict(deque)
    for x in lst:
        count[key(x)].append(x)

    order = sorted(count)
    output = []

    for x in cycle(order):
        if len(output) == len(lst):
            break
        if count[x]:
            output.append(count[x].popleft())

    return output
```

### Example

```
import random

lst = random.choices(range(5), k=15)

print('list:', lst)
print('sorted:', chess_sort(lst))
```

### Output

```
list: [0, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2]
sorted: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0]
```

### Applying to your problem

Notice how I allowed to pass a `key` to `chess_sort`? You can use it as you would for `sorted` to sort your items by `branch` attribute.

```
chess_sort(Item.objects.all(), key=lambda x: x.branch)
```

Comment: I think you have solved more than you were asked to: you actually gave a meaningful formulation of "chess sorting" for the OP. Kudos!

Comment: Thanks! I think I will spend some time comprehending how this works. But it does work!

Comment: @user1537546 don't be shy to ask if you need to. Cheers!

Comment: The only error in this method is that it reverses the initial array. So it should be `for x in lst[::-1]: count[key(x)].append(x)`

Comment: @diveru4i I was using pop() to pop in O(1), but if the order matters see the updated solution using a dequeue. dequeue's append and popleft are both O(1)